# How to gradually slow down animation

Tags: animation

Hi i need to slow down animation, but gradually. I have 3 keyframes, first with linear interpolation, and i want linear motion up to second keyframe. But then, from the second one, i want to animation (rotating object) be smoothly slowed down. If i use bezier interpolation, it will firstly speed up rotation, and then slow down. I need some interpolation or method that will slow down rotation from second to third keyframe. I mean something like reversed easing....

Comment: Use the Graph editor, just a sec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the *Graph Editor*, find the first keyframe, select it and press <kbd>V</kbd> *> Vector*. Then press <kbd>RMB</kbd> on the right handle, and move it so it is a straight line to the next point on the graph, and then press <kbd>LMB</kbd>:

[image: Graph Editor]

This will make the object begin at and maintain the same speed, until it is time to slow down, when the standard ease method will be used.

[image: Animated Example]

Answer (score 3):

Go to the ***Graph Editor*** and shape the transformation curve as pictured below. Now select the start point of the transformation curve, press <kbd>T</kbd> and set the keyframe interpolation type to *Linear*. 
[image]

Having a keyframe in the middle of the curve may allow you to manipulate it and change the easing speed. Select the middle point and change its position using <kbd>G</kbd>. Grab the handle and scale it (<kbd>S</kbd>) to change the curvature (easing speed).
[image]