# Modify degree of Bezier interpolation between keyframes for animating an object

Tags: python, animation, bezier-curves

I'm trying to animate motion of objects. For this, I'm setting the location and rotation of the objects at certain frames and marking them as keyframes. By default, blender uses Bezier interpolation so that the motion starts slowly, increases speed in the middle and then starts decreasing to 0 at the end keyframe.

However for certain cases, the initial motion is too slow that there is hardly any motion between the frames, but the motion in the middle to too high. Is it possible to modify this slightly such that there is some initial motion and the motion in the middle is not too high?

I know I can use linear interpolation. That will be my last resort. But if Bezier interpolation works, it'll be great. Additionally, I can't do this [manually](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26360/101146). I have about 200 blend files and I need to do this for every one of them. So, I would prefer if there is some setting that I can change via python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by right clicking the timeline and choosing the option "Interpolation mode".

[image]

To the right are all the interpolations that are available. In your case since you do not want the Bezier interpolation, you can choose Linear interpolation which interpolates with constant speed. There are bunch of other interpolation modes too if you want to try them out (check image).

Comment: It's not what I was looking for, but it solves my problem. Thanks!